# Save records selected in a multi-select listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to write code for a save button, which is supposed to save data from all rows selected in a multi-select listbox. This is my code:

```
Dim strID As String, strFullName As String, strUsedNumber As String, strUsedAddress As String, strUsedPosition As String
Dim iCurrRow As Integer
strID = txtID
strFullName = txtFullName
strUsedNumber = lstTest.Column(0, iCurrRow)
strUsedAddress = lstTest.Column(1, iCurrRow)
strUsedPosition = lstTest.Column(2, iCurrRow)

iCurrRow = 0
Do While (iCurrRow < lstTest.ListCount)
    If lstTest.Selected(iCurrRow) Then
        IO_TestData.saveInfoUsedInTestData strID, strFullName, strUsedNumber, strUsedAddress, strUsedPosition
    End If
    iCurrRow = iCurrRow + 1
Loop
```

Currently it saves only the first row of the listbox - if you select i.e. three rows from the list, it tries to save the first row three times. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the variables for

```
strUsedNumber = lstTest.Column(0, iCurrRow)
strUsedAddress = lstTest.Column(1, iCurrRow)
strUsedPosition = lstTest.Column(2, iCurrRow)
```

Outside the loop, hence they never change.